vlookup after combining cells
I have a VBA code that has to vlookup data from a few different files group and sort them. At the end, there is a column that combines the data with '/' if it's different between the two files it's coming from. The combined data is in cell C and all is working perfectly to this point.
I want to make a check of column C with another database in Sheet2 in one of the files, however the code that I have for that is returning only NA. Where am I wrong?
These are the mentions that are taken to sheet2 and vlookup-ed with the data on the next picture



This is the code I am using.

Sub PerformVLookup(mention As String, lookupRange2 As Range, lookupRange4 As Range, lookupRange2Sheet2 As Range, wsOutput As Worksheet, outputRow As Long)
    Dim lookupValue1 As String
    Dim lookupValue2 As String ' For the value in column C
    Dim lookupResult2 As Variant
    Dim lookupResult4 As Variant
    Dim lookupResultSheet2 As Variant ' Result for lookup in Sheet2
    Dim combinedResult As String
    
    lookupValue1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(CStr(mention)))
   
    ' Perform the VLOOKUP for this mention in Workbook2
    On Error Resume Next
    lookupResult2 = Application.VLookup(lookupValue1, lookupRange2, 2, False)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If IsError(lookupResult2) Then
        lookupResult2 = "#N/A"
    End If
    
    
    ' Perform the VLOOKUP for this mention in Workbook4
    On Error Resume Next
    lookupResult4 = Application.VLookup(lookupValue1, lookupRange4, 2, False)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If IsError(lookupResult4) Then
        lookupResult4 = "#N/A"
    End If
    
   ' Combine the results
    combinedResult = ""
    If lookupResult2 <> "#N/A" Then combinedResult = lookupResult2
    If lookupResult4 <> "#N/A" Then
        If combinedResult <> "" And combinedResult <> lookupResult4 Then
            combinedResult = combinedResult & " \ " & lookupResult4
        ElseIf combinedResult = "" Then
            combinedResult = lookupResult4
        End If
    End If
    
    ' If no matches, display #N/A
    If combinedResult = "" Then
        combinedResult = "#N/A"
    End If
    
    ' Output the final combined result in Column C
    wsOutput.Cells(outputRow, 3).Value = combinedResult
    
    ' If the combined result has "\", apply the color fill #FDBAB5 (light red)
    If InStr(combinedResult, "\") > 0 Then
        wsOutput.Cells(outputRow, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(253, 186, 181)
    End If
    
    ' Now perform the VLOOKUP for the value in column C in Workbook2 Sheet2
     If Not IsEmpty(wsOutput.Cells(outputRow, 3).Value) Then
        lookupValue2 = CStr(wsOutput.Cells(outputRow, 3).Value) ' Ensure lookupValue2 is a string
    On Error Resume Next
    lookupResultSheet2 = Application.VLookup(lookupValue2, lookupRange2Sheet2, 2, False)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If IsError(lookupResultSheet2) Then
        lookupResultSheet2 = "#N/A"
    End If
    
    ' Output the result from Workbook2 Sheet2 in column D
    wsOutput.Cells(outputRow, 4).Value = lookupResultSheet2
    Else
        ' If column C is empty, output NA in column D
        wsOutput.Cells(outputRow, 4).Value = "#N/A"
    End If
End Sub



It would be helpful to post only the relevant code (it's not obvious to anyone where your current issues are in that listing), and to show us at least a screenshot of the data you're trying to match up.  There's no way for us to know why all you get is #N/A.

GroupMentionsSortedAndVLookupThreeWorkbooks() is too big. A function should never take up more then 1 screen worth of code. You need to break it down into many smaller functions to allow anyone else to understand and maintain it.

PerformVLookup() has an issue at the end with indentation. It is not clear what IF the ELSE is associated with.

I just added screenshots as an example of the data I am using and also left only the code that is relevant to the problem I am trying to solve

Please review your calculation for lastCol = wsSource.Cells(1, wsSource.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column.  You might want xlToRight

This can be completed without VLookUp.  Inherently you want to Match() a value against a range, whereupon you can Index() the result or simply allow the row to display from Match().  The options include looping on the sheet, or if it's a manageable data set (sub 10k rows) you can take as an array and loop.  Have you thought about other options?

Additionally, your screenshots are not giving sufficient information.  What is the expected outcome?  What is the initial?  Both screenshots are currently the same image.

Can you show us the "Column C" values you're trying to match ?  FYI you can remove all the On Error Resume Next / On Error Goto 0 wrapped around Application.Vlookup - a non-match will not raise any runtime error, and you risk hiding some other problem by suppressing errors there.

In your screenshots it seems clear that oneset of values is numeric (right-aligned, screenshot #3) and the other is numbers stored as text (left-aligned, screenshot #2).   If you recall your previous question vlookup will not make a match in that scenario.

May I ask which version of Excel you're using?

What values do you have in the first column of lookupRange2Sheet2? If they are not 99,500,… but sale,store,…, lookupResultSheet2 will be #N/A.

Not addressing your immediate problem, but some suggestions to reduce the bulk of your code by factoring out common pieces of logic/functionality into separate methods which you can re-use.
(Untested)
Sub PerformVLookup(mention As String, lookupRange2 As Range, lookupRange4 As Range, lookupRange2Sheet2 As Range, wsOutput As Worksheet, outputRow As Long)
    Const NO_MATCH As String = "#N/A"  'use Const for fixed values
    
    Dim lookupValue1 As String, lookupValue2 As String ' For the value in column C
    Dim lookupResult2 As Variant, lookupResult4 As Variant, lookupResultSheet2 As Variant
    Dim combinedResult As String, c As Range
    
    '## are you sure this gives a value which can be matched to the other sheets? ##
    lookupValue1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(CStr(mention)))
   
    ' Perform the VLOOKUP for this mention in Workbook2
    lookupResult2 = VLookupOrDefault(lookupValue1, lookupRange2, 2, NO_MATCH)
    lookupResult4 = VLookupOrDefault(lookupValue1, lookupRange4, 2, NO_MATCH)
    
    combinedResult = CombineUniquesOrDefault(" \ ", NO_MATCH, NO_MATCH, lookupResult2, lookupResult4)
    
    ' Output the final combined result in Column C
    Set c = wsOutput.Cells(outputRow, 3)
    c.Value = combinedResult
    If InStr(combinedResult, "\") > 0 Then c.Interior.Color = RGB(253, 186, 181)
    
    ' Now perform the VLOOKUP for the value in column C in Workbook2 Sheet2
     If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
        wsOutput.Cells(outputRow, 4).Value = _
            VLookupOrDefault(CStr(c.Value), lookupRange2Sheet2, 2, NO_MATCH )
    Else
        ' If column C is empty, output NA in column D
        wsOutput.Cells(outputRow, 4).Value = NO_MATCH 
    End If
End Sub

'Perform a vlookup and return `defaultValue` if there's no match
'Or consider using `Application.Xlookup`, wich allows you to specify
'   a default value if no match...
Function VLookupOrDefault(lookupValue, lookupRange As Range, _
                          colNum As Long, Optional defaultValue)
    VLookupOrDefault = Application.VLookup(lookupValue, lookupRange, 2, False)
    If IsError(VLookupOrDefault) And Not IsMissing(defaultValue) Then VLookupOrDefault = ""
End Function

'Combine all unique values passed to `values()`, except for any value matching `ignoreValue`
'  Return unique values joined by `sep`.  If there are no values to return then return `defaultValue`
Function CombineUniquesOrDefault(sep As String, ignoreValue As String, _
                                defaultValue As String, ParamArray values()) As String
    Dim dict As Object, el
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each el In values
        If el <> ignoreValue Then dict(el) = True
    Next el
    If dict.Count > 0 Then
        CombineUniquesOrDefault = Join(dict.Keys, sep)
    Else
        CombineUniquesOrDefault = defaultValue
    End If
End Function


This will look at a simple one-sheet structure to check your data on another sheet:
Function checkValueAgainstSource(lookUpVal1 As String, lookUpVal2 As String, srcRange1 As Range, srcRange2 As Range) As String
    If srcRange1.Rows.Count <> srcRange2.Rows.Count And srcRange1.Row <> srcRange2.Row Then
        checkValueAgainstSource = "Source ranges not equivalent"
    Else
        Dim rowNum As Long, output As String:  For rowNum = srcRange1.Row To srcRange1.Row + srcRange1.Rows.Count - 1
            If Trim(lookUpVal1) = srcRange1(rowNum) And Trim(lookUpVal2) = srcRange2(rowNum) Then
                output = srcRange1(rowNum) & "/" & srcRange2(rowNum)
                Exit For
            Else
                output = "No match"
            End If
        Next rowNum
        checkValueAgainstSource = output
    End If
End Function

If I am interpolating the request correctly, you are checking results for two values against two separate ranges in another sheet, and if those are found on the same line/row, you would output the combination of the two values with a "/" between, e.g., Sale/4D for row 7 using cell 1 and cell 2 values.
Rather than using VLookUp(), I have simply looped through the range, as you have a known location for each value being reviewed.
Note that I only look at a single sheet, where you want to look at multiple, but this is a quick example of how to get there.

My sheet1 data:

My sheet2 data:


Post-script:  I did this in VBA so you can take the model and add other sheets/checks, though if you were to just check a single sheet, you could perform this with a formula... =Match(A1&"/"&B1,Sheets2!A1:A5&"/"Sheets2!B1:B5,0).

Though you're looking for a VBA solution, here's a suggestion using formulas and conditional formatting:

Using dynamic array formulas, in the first cell of "Final Combined Result":
=LET(
    items, TRIM(CLEAN(G2:G14)),
    lookupRange2, A2:B14,
    lookupResult2, XLOOKUP(
        items,
        TRIM(CLEAN(INDEX(lookupRange2, , 1))),
        INDEX(lookupRange2, , 2)
    ),
    lookupRange4, D2:E14,
    lookupResult4, XLOOKUP(
        items,
        TRIM(CLEAN(INDEX(lookupRange4, , 1))),
        INDEX(lookupRange4, , 2)
    ),
    combinedTemp, IFS(
        (IFNA(lookupResult2, "") <> "") *
            (IFNA(lookupResult4, "") <> ""),
        lookupResult2 &
            IF(
                lookupResult2 = lookupResult4,
                "",
                " \ " & lookupResult4
            ),
        TRUE,
        IFNA(lookupResult2, "") & IFNA(lookupResult4, "")
    ),
    combined, IF(combinedTemp <> "", combinedTemp, NA()),
    combined
)

in the first cell of "Check":
=LET(
    lookupValue2, I2#,
    lookupRange2Sheet2, Sheet2!A2:B14,
    XLOOKUP(
        lookupValue2,
        INDEX(lookupRange2Sheet2, , 2) & "",
        INDEX(lookupRange2Sheet2, , 2)
    )
)

